# Fill a form from a select box selection

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have mutiple forms that are used to insert information into a mysql database. That all works fine.

I now want to be able to fill a form using the info from the database by selecting something in a selectbox.

What I don't want to do is code a page for each table. I would like to have the form created dynamically depending on what is selected in the selectbox. Is this possible? Can PHP examine what tables I have and then create a form and populate that form from the relevant table based on what is selected in the selectbox?

At the moment I am using old mysql and not mysqli or PDO. I will have to get someone else to update the code to mysqli or PDO as I have no idea about that. So for now, I just need to get the basics up and running and then I can hand it over to somebody to correct the outdated mysql code. So if you could please help me based on mysql and not mysqli or PDO?

Comment: Put your code in question to get helped

Answer (score 0):

To make changes on your web page you can use for example jQuery

```
$('select').on('change', function() { 
  // Do your stuff for example
  $('form > input').val('Awesome');
});
```